# Spring - could not locate an image in controller - servletContext is null

Tags: spring, maven, svg

I'm writing a simple svg parser, but i cannot load the svg in the controller to use it...

this method should load the file to get a DOM document

```
public class SVGParser implements ServletContextAware{
    final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SVGParser.class);

    private ServletContext servletContext;

public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
            this.servletContext = servletContext;

        }

    public Document getDocument(){

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        InputStream is;
        Document document = null;
        String realPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/resources/images/disegno.svg");
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(realPath);
            logger.debug("IS = "+is.toString());
            document = builder.parse(is);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return document;
    }
```

The problem is that i get a NullPointException because servletContext is null to get realPath();

This is the tree of my maven directory organization:

```
SVG
|-src/main/java
|-src/main/resources
|-src
|-target
    |-SVG
        |-META-INF
        |-WEB-INF
              |-resources
                    |-images
                         |-disegno.svg
```

How can I understand which is the right position of my files inside the war?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getResourceAsStream method attempts to find the file by searching the CLASSPATH.
The file you are attempting to load is not on the CLASSPATH.
Try something like:

```
final String realPath = ServletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/resources/images/disegno.svg");

final InputStream = new FileInputStream(realPath);
```

*Edit*
Implement the ServletContextAware interface in the SVGParser class.

Comment: I'm getting a NullPointException in 
 `private String realPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/resources/images/disegno.svg");` but the file exists in that position...

Comment: Ok, the problem is that servletContext is null, maybe I don't know how to instantiate it..

Comment: Do you have a servlet class or do you have Spring handler classes (perhaps with @RequestMapping annotations)?

Comment: I use spring classes, but this method it's not in a controller, so there is no @RequestMapping for it

Comment: I tried to implement ServletContextAware, but i continue to get null in my servletContext, do I miss something? I'll edit the first question

Comment: SVGParser  must be a bean that spring creates.